# Amazon S3 Cloud architecture

Tags: php, amazon-s3, naming-conventions, cloud, storage

I'm writing an app that let's you share files in the cloud.
You make a user-account and can upload your files with and send links to friends.

I'm using Amazon S3 to save the data.
But I'm not sure how I should proceed.

There are buckets, which you can create in S3, and in those buckets you save your files.
I thought about making a bucket for each user, but then I read that you can only have 100 buckets at a time.

Isn't there a better way to managing this then to just save all user files in one "directory".
This will get so messy. I have never used S3 before, I would be very thankful for any advice.
And if this is the only way, what naming convention proved to be the best?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though S3 has a flat structure within a bucket, each object has its own path much like the directories you're used to.

So you can structure your paths like so:

```
/<user-id>/<album-1>/...
```

One thing to keep in mind is that not all directory related features are available, such as:

- Deny access to `/<user-123>/*`,
- Copy from one directory to another.

Comment: Ok... You mean just as a naming convention? or can you actually store them in different paths?

Comment: @IlijaTovilo The path is a property of the object, so yes :)

Comment: Ok, stupid me :D
Just saw it. 
But one last question:
Do you think it would be better storing the file paths in a database, so you can generate file-names to prevent naming-conflicts?

Comment: @IlijaTovilo You should treat it just like your local storage, so using a database to generate your file names is probably a good idea :)